# How to decode multipart/related responses in WCF?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, soap

I have a webservice that returns the result as `multipart/related`:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary=MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_FCAC227A0F1D534C2D1349803588825;
type="application/soap+xml"; start="<0.urn:uuid:FCAC227A0F1D534C2D1349803588826@apache.org>"; action="urn:MyServiceAction"
Date: Tue, 09 Oct 2012 17:26:28 GMT
Content-Length: 2961

--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_FCAC227A0F1D534C2D1349803588825
Content-Type: application/soap+xml; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-ID: <0.urn:uuid:FCAC227A0F1D534C2D1349803588826@apache.org>

<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
[... snipped ...]
</soapenv:Envelope>
--MIMEBoundaryurn_uuid_FCAC227A0F1D534C2D1349803588825--
```

WCF seems to not support that. I'm using a custom binding and the `TextMessageEncodingBindingElement` blows up with a message telling me that the content type isn't supported. `MtomMessageEncodingBindingElement` also complains because it doesn't expect `application/soap+xml` but `application/xop+xml`.

Is there a MessageEncoder that can properly handle `multipart/related` for `application/soap+xml`? Or is there an easy way for me to hook into the pipeline and extract the payload before it gets sent to `TextMessageEncodingBindingElement`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a standard for combining SOAP with MIME called SOAP With Attachments (SwA, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOAP_with_Attachments ). If this is what you're using, there's a custom encoder for it here: http://wcfswaencoder.codeplex.com/
Even if it's not SwA, the custom encoder code may be a good starting point for you.

Comment: Thanks, the Custom Encoder was a great starting point since it did the MIME Parsing and allowed me to build the other pieces out properly.